# ApexOrgWideCoverage history

Tags: apex, code-coverage

The below tooling API returns the org wide coverage, it is working fine . do we know how to get teh history of the coverage. say how is teh coverage in the last week and to see over the period?

SELECT+PercentCovered+FROM+ApexOrgWideCoverage

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that it is not possible to retrieve the org code coverage for the past as it will only have one field "PercentCovered" on the [ApexOrgWideCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexorgwidecoverage.htm) which will be calculated and returned when you run the below query.

```
Select PercentCovered from ApexOrgWideCoverage
```